# Guardando datos de un formulario con un modal de bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap, laravel-5

Tengo un modal con un formulario y cuando le doy al botón para guardar los datos que he introducido, no me manda a la dirección/ruta que está definida en el atributo action de la etiqueta form, y por tanto no me guarda dato alguno en la base de datos, ¿qué tendría que hacer para que me enviara los datos al controlador? 
Aquí el formulario modal:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog"
 tabindex="-1" id="comentario-{{$lib->lib_no}}" >
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('comenta.store') }}">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">


        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Comentario</h4>

            </div>



                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <label for="cmt_titulo">Título</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cmt_titulo" placeholder="Título...">

                    <br>
                        <label for="cmt_texto">Escribe tu comentario</label>
                    <br>
                        <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="cmt_texto" placeholder="Escribe tu comentario..."></textarea>
                    <br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmt_libro_no" value="{{$lib->lib_no}}">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Guardar</button>
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

y este es el metodo del controlador:

```
public function store(ComentarioFormRequest $request){

    $comentario= new Comentario;
    $comentario->cmt_no=0;

    $fecha=Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid');
    $comentario->cmt_fecha=$fecha->toDateString();
    $comentario->cmt_titulo=$request->get('cmt_titulo');
    $comentario->cmt_texto=$request->get('cmt_texto');


    $comentario->cmt_cliente_id=auth()->user()->u_cliente_id;

    $comentario->cmt_libro_id=Libro::select('id_libro')->where('lib_no', $request->get('cmt_libro_no'));
    $comentario->cmt_activo=1;
    $comentario->save();

    $comentario2=Comentario::orderBy('id_comentario', 'desc')
        ->first();

    Comentario::where('id_comentario', $comentario2->id_comentario)
        ->update(['cmt_no'=>++$comentario2->id_comentario]);


    return Redirect::to('cliente/comenta');
}
```

No llega nada a este form request:

```
 <?php

namespace libreir\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ComentarioFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'cmt_no'=> 'integer',
        'cmt_fecha'=>'date',
        'cmt_titulo'=>'string|required',
        'cmt_texto'=>'string|required',
        'msj_cliente_id'=>'integer',
        'cmt_libro_id'=>'integer|required',
        'cmt_activo'=>'integer|max:1|min:0'

    ];
}
```

}

Comment: ¿qué trae el Request?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que es lo que manda? La cosa es que no llega a mandar nada, pero ahora subo lo que tengo en mi archivo formrequest que es lo que me pide para entrar en el controlador

Comment: Si haces un dump o dd del request, ¿está vacío? Por lo que dices pareciera que creaste más de un formulario y estás enviando el formulario incorrecto.

Comment: Cierto, creo más de un formulario, porque creo un modal por cada fila de la tabla, y con respecto al request no se como verlo, ¿en la plantilla .blade te permite verlo? Porque en el controlador no entra...

Comment: En la pregunta anterior que hiciste te hice una pregunta en un comentario y no tuve respuesta.... la hago de nuevo: ¿es necesario crear tantos modales? yo crearía solo uno...

Comment: Ah perdona, se me habrá pasado... Emmm.. Es que si no ¿como le pasas el id del libro seleccionado? No se me ocurre otra idea, además hice un proyecto anterior con los modales de borrado y no me daba problema...

Comment: ¿Qué versión de bootstrap?

Comment: ¿En el controlador usas `ComentarioFormRequest` pero luego muestras `PedidoFormRequest`?

Comment: Cierto Iosu, lo acabo de solventar, un error, perdona. Con respecto a la versión de bootstrap que uso es la 3.3.7, más concretamente el array de devDependencies me pone:  "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una buena idea en esta ocasión es crear únicamente un modal, si tuvieras 1000 registros que necesiten un modal, no sería práctico generar 1000 modales.

```
<div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog"
 tabindex="-1" id="comentario" >
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('comenta.store') }}">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Comentario</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                <label for="cmt_titulo">Título</label>
                <input type="text" name="cmt_titulo" placeholder="Título...">
                <label for="cmt_texto">Escribe tu comentario</label>
                <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="cmt_texto" placeholder="Escribe tu comentario..."></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="cmt_libro_no" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo único que cambia es que el id del modal no depende del id del libro, y eliminamos el valor del campo `cmt_libro_no`.

```
<a href="" data-target="#comentario"  data-toggle="modal" class="comment-button">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  data-norden="{{$lib->lib_no}}">Comentar</button></a>
```

Ahora todo lo que tienes que hacer es capturar el "click" que haces en cualquier botón "Comentar" (agrega una clase a dicho botón) y obtener el valor del id del libro, el cual veo que ya tienes almacenado en el atributo `data-norden`. Una vez tengas ese valor, lo asignas al valor del campo `cmt_libro_no`.

Voy a plantear una solución con jQuery, teniendo en cuenta que usas Bootstrap:

```
$('.comment-button').click(function (e) {
    $("input[name='cmt_libro_no']").val(
        $(this).find('button').first().data('norden'));
});
```